# How to type function's return to be an array of instances of a dynamic class via .phpstorm.meta.php file?

Tags: phpstorm

With `.phpstorm.meta.php` you can overwrite the return type of your class methods. For example:

```
// .phpstorm.meta.php 

namespace PHPSTORM_META
{
    $STATIC_METHOD_TYPES = [
      \Acme\Node::closest('') => [
         "" == "@",
      ],
    ];
}
```

The example above lets PhpStorm understand the return of `$node->closest(SomeNodeType::class)` is an instance of `SomeNodeType`.

However, my question is how to make PhpStorm understand that a function returns an array of instances of a given type.

For example:
`$node->findAllOfType(SomeNodeType::class)` would return an array of `SomeNodeType` instances (normally one would use `SomeNodeType[]` if it would not be dynamic).

Attempts to use `"@[]"` or `"@Iterator"` instead of `"@"`, in the above code example, failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's simply [not supported](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-27832#comment=27-1106663) ... unless you can try and list all possible types manually instead of using single generic rule (which *may* work in theory -- sorry, have not tried it myself).

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-27832 -- watch that and related tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Comment: Too bad it's not supported, but thanks for noting! Will keep tracking the issue and update ones anything changes.